# $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$ transformation, transform it to $f(x) = g(x)\ln(x)$

Tags: logarithms

$f(x) = \ln(x+1)$

Is there a way to transform the Equation above to a simpler one, that will include only $f(x) = g(x)\ln(x)$ kind of function?

Comment: There is no "Equation above"

Comment: the function is $ln(x+1)$

Comment: but $\ln (x+1)$ is defined for $ x=0$, while $f(x)\ln (x)$ isn't

Comment: ln(x+1) isn't an equation, neither is it a function if not defined else. It's a term. You have not defined f(x) = ln(x+1)

Comment: edited, I meant $f(x) = ln(x+1)$

Comment: If you type \ln(x) instead of ln(x) it looks better: $\ln(x)$ vs $ln(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If:
$$\ln (x+1) = f(x) \ln x$$

then:

$$f(x) = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln x}$$

This cannot be simplified. You could write $f(x) = \log_x(x+1)$, but we generally use logarithms with constant bases (hopefully $e$, that's the simplest base) so it is not a good idea to do so.

Comment: So there is no way to simplify this function?

Comment: There are no log rules that would apply. Anything that might "look" simpler would just be hiding details from you without actually being simpler, like sneaking the same variable into the base and the exponent.